# How do you go from $y'=\frac{1}{x+y^2}$ to $\frac{dx}{dy}-x=y^2$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve
> $$y'=\frac{1}{x+y^2}\tag{1}\label{eq: 1}$$
> Written in this form, it is a non linear equation. However, if we write it as
> $$\frac{dx}{dy}-x=y^2\tag{2}\label{eq: 2}$$
> it turns into a linear equation. We have inverted, however, the roles of dependent variable with the one of independent variable. That is, instead of looking for $y$ as a function of $x$ we look for $x$ as a function of $y$.

How was this done? What is the process one should follow to go from $\ref{eq: 1}$ to $\ref{eq: 2}$?

Comment: Formally, if $y'=dy/dx$ then $1/y'=dx/dy$, hence $dx/dy=x+y^2$.

Comment: As a side note, when reading about the inverse function theorem, as cited in the answer of Luke Collins, note the excerpt: "a sufficient condition for a function to be invertible in a neighborhood of a point in its domain: namely, that its derivative is continuous and non-zero at the point."  One of the consequences of this is that the function is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing in a neighborhood around the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do as David G. Stork suggests in his comment, you get the desired equation.

If you want a more rigorous justification as to why you can go from asking about $y=y(x)$ to $x=x(y)$, you need to look at the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).

Comment: Well the part of the inverse function theorem used here is $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}} $.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most mathematically correct but see as follows:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x+y^{2}}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}\left(x+y^{2}\right)=1$

$x+y^{2}=\frac{dx}{dy}$

$y^2 = \frac{dx}{dy} - x$

$\frac{dx}{dy}-x=y^2$